# Autoclose bootstrap 5 Dropdown without toggle in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a search field that shows data as dropdown.item when user is typing. The library is React Bootstrap (bootstrap 5). This is working great. The dropdown is showing. The problem is that the dropdown persist when clicking outside or navigating to a new link. The dropdown is in a header that does not get rerendered with the rest of the page. Using NextJS. Any tips on how to close a dropdown that has no toggle?

```
   <form className="d-none d-sm-inline-block" style={{ zIndex: "1000" }}>
  <div className="input-group input-group-navbar">
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder="Søk"
      aria-label="Search"
      onChange={(event) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
      }}
    />

    <button className="btn" type="button">
      <Icon.Search className="align-middle" />
    </button>
  </div>
  {searchData.length >= 1 && (
    <Dropdown style={{ position: "absolute", background: "white" }} autoClose="outside">
      {searchData.slice(0, 10).map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <Link key={element.agressoResourceId} href={`employees/69918`} passHref replace={true}>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              {element.firstname} - {element.lastname}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </Dropdown>
  )}
</form>
```

Comment: It works if a add the           <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-autoclose-true"></Dropdown.Toggle>
But i dont want a button in the top of search results that the users have to click.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use onBlur event and hide the dropdown. The problem comes with the onblure is triggered before you press the item. The solution here was to use a setTimeout of 200ms.